# Consigo chamar uma função dentro do Validators, em um formulário reativo?

Tags: angular

Fiz um método e gostaria de usar ele como Validators, em um formulário reativo, no Angular 2.
É possível?

```
controle(){
    let data : number = this.formCep('nasc').value.split("-")[2];
    let atual = new Date().getFullYear();
    if(data - atual <= 17){
        alert('Você ainda não é maior de idade.')
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


nasc: [null, [
    Validators.required,
    CustomValidators.minDate('1917-12-31'),
    CustomValidators.maxDate(new Date())
    ]
],
```

Answer (score 0):

sim. por exemplo:

```
 descricao: [null, [ this.validarObrigatoriedade ] ]

 validarObrigatoriedade(input: FormControl) {
    return (input.value ? null : { obrigatoriedade: true });
  }
```